# Store bootstrap toggle in store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Is there a way to store a toggled vue-bootstrap view in a vuex store?

```
    <div class="mb-5 mt-5">
        <button class="mr-2 button_class" v-b-toggle="'searchByName searchBySeason'">toggle</button>
    </div>
    
    <b-collapse id="searchByName" visible>
      // stuff
    </b-collapse>

    <b-collapse id="searchBySeason">
      // stuff
    </b-collapse>
```

I wanna store the state of the toggled element so it'll still be there after reloading the page.

Comment: I think, you can save the state of the toggled element in browser's localStorage or on server, and return it state by API.

Comment: @YuriyPiskunov But how would I access the state of the element? That's my main problem here with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a property to `<b-collapse>`'s `v-model`, which will be `true` or `false` depending on the collapses state.

You can then for example use a computed property with a getter/setter to get and set your store state.

```html
<template> 
  <b-collapse v-model="isNameCollapseOpen" id="searchByName">
    // stuff
  </b-collapse>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    isNameCollapseOpen: {
      get() {
        // Get state from store
        return this.$store.state.isNameCollapseOpen
      },
      set(isOpen) {
        // Update store using a mutation
        this.$store.commit('SET_NAME_COLLAPSE_STATE', isOpen)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Be aware that things saved in Vuex doesn't persist between page loads, meaning if you reload the page, the state is lost by default.
However, there are plugins to persist store state, like [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) or [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate).

#### Example

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isNameCollapseOpen: false
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_NAME_COLLAPSE_STATE(state, isVisible) {
      state.isNameCollapseOpen = isVisible
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store: store,
  computed: {
    isNameCollapseOpen: {
      get() {
        // Get state from store
        return this.$store.state.isNameCollapseOpen
      },
      set(isOpen) {
        // Update store using a mutation
        this.$store.commit('SET_NAME_COLLAPSE_STATE', isOpen)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-btn v-b-toggle.search-by-name>Toggle collapse</b-btn>

  <b-collapse v-model="isNameCollapseOpen" id="search-by-name">
    Some text
  </b-collapse>
  <hr /> Store state: {{ $store.state.isNameCollapseOpen }}
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried it like this, but it didn't work. Cause it must be toggled with the "v-b-toggle" propertie. So just being aware if something is toggled or not won't help me. But it also must be toggeld depending on this state.

Comment: v-b-toggle will still work and change the store state accordingly.